# SQL reducing balance statement

Tags: sql

I would like to create a table using SQL, that shows how a principal loan balance amortises over time.

I have a cash flow table;

```
- ID        Rate Date      Amount
- Loan 1    20% 01/01/2018  -100.00
- Loan 1    20% 01/02/2018  21.00
- Loan 1    20% 01/03/2018  21.00
- Loan 1    20% 01/04/2018  21.00
- Loan 1    20% 01/05/2018  21.00
- Loan 1    20% 01/06/2018  21.00
```

I would like to produce an amortisation schedule similar to the one below;

```
- ID        Date       Days Opening Interest Rental Closing
- Loan 1    01/02/2018  31  -100.00 -1.70   21.00   -80.70 
- Loan 1    01/03/2018  28  -80.70  -1.24   21.00   -60.94 
- Loan 1    01/04/2018  31  -60.94  -1.04   21.00   -40.97 
- Loan 1    01/05/2018  30  -40.97  -0.67   21.00   -20.65 
- Loan 1    01/06/2018  31  -20.65  -0.35   21.00   -0.00
```

Where:

```
Interest = opening balance  * rate /365 * days
Days = number of days since last cash flow event
Closing balance = opening + Interest + Rental
```

The issue I am having is bring the closing balance forward as the opening balance in the next row

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice on this.

Comment: You need to provide the table structure of the tables you are using (in particular it is not clear if rate is a varchar which will make a difference to how you use that field) and show what sql you have already tried.

Comment: ID (VARCHAR), RATE(VARCHAR), DATE(DATE), AMOUNT(FLOAT)

Answer (score 0):

use order by clause like below

```
order by closingbalance desc
```

Comment: thanks but how do I carry the closing balance forward as the opening on the next row?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [lag function](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-lag-function/) you can look at previous rows in a table so:

```
SELECT
ID,
date,
...
lag(closing_balance,1)OVER(partition by ID ORDER BY date) as opening balance,
...
FROM cash_flow_table
```

Will give you the previous days closing balance as today's opening balance.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of LAG, but the closing_balance is not available in the cashflow table.

Comment: @Tiger You can put the calculation of 'closing_balance' as the table you call it from then. Perhaps I'm missing something, do you want to elaborate on what you're struggling with?

Comment: Thank Lio.  The calculated field (Closing Balance), needs to be carried forward as the opening line on the next row (as the opening balance).  The calculation then repeats.  Opening balance + Interest - Payment = Closing Balance.

Comment: @Tiger Have you got an example of the sql you're using the calculate closing balance?

Comment: I am still in the conceptual stage so have not even started writing code yet.   I am reluctant but it feels like I will have to introduce a loop to write each line to a table.

Comment: I am still in the conceptual stage so have not even started writing code yet.   I am reluctant but it feels like I will have to introduce a loop to write each line to a table.

Comment: @Tiger Okay, we aren't here to write code for you so it is nice to see your attempts first. Perhaps you could give it a go yourself and update your question with your attempts before we go any further with this?

Comment: How would you begin to structure the code in order to solve the problem.  Is it even possible without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT ID,
       RATE,
       DATE,
       AMOUNT,
       (Date - previous_withdrawal_date) as Days,
       opening_balance,
       opening_balance * rate /365 * (Date - previous_withdrawal_date) as Interest,
       Rental,
       (opening_balance + Interest + Rental) as Closing_Balance
  FROM (
    SELECT lag (Date) OVER (partition by ID order by date) as previous_withdrawal_date,
           NVL(lag (AMOUNT) OVER (partition by ID order by date), AMOUNT) as opening_balance,
           cf.*
      FROM cash_flow cf);
```

Let me know if it works as per your requirement.

Thanks,
Idrees

Comment: Thanks @ihm017, my problem is that the LAG(Amount) is not the new opening balance.  The opening balance is the closing balance from the previous line